# React useKeyPress hook getting triggered automatically on page load, but shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-listener

I'm listening for a keypress event, but it's getting triggered automatically every time the page loads, and I seriously need it to wait for someone to actually press a key. I'm chasing my tail at this point so any help is appreciated!

Here's the code for the hook:

```
export function useKeyPress(targetKey) {
  // State for keeping track of whether key is pressed
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);
  // If pressed key is our target key then set to true
  function downHandler({ key }) {
    if (key === targetKey) {
      setKeyPressed(true);
    }
  }
  // If released key is our target key then set to false
  const upHandler = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === targetKey) {
      setKeyPressed(false);
    }
  };
  // Add event listeners
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
    // Remove event listeners on cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
    };
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount

  return keyPressed;
}
```

And here's where it's getting called:

```
  const goToTodayKeypress = useKeyPress('t');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimelineDate(dayjs());
    scrollToPosition();
  }, [goToTodayKeypress]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel a little silly. useKeyPress is just returning a boolean, so all I had to do was wrap the useEffect in a condition:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (goToTodayKeypress){
      setTimelineDate(dayjs());
      scrollToPosition();
    }
  }, [goToTodayKeypress]);
```